# Manifest definition issue deploying Hangfire .net Core 2.1 MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

I'm trying to deploy a Hangfire ASP.net Core 2.1 MVC Hangfire app.

It works locally but when I deploy it I get this error:

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Hangfire.SqlServer, Version=1.6.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I'm hosting other .net Core 2.1 MVC sites fine.

Usually in the past - in different non Hangfire apps - a manifest definition error came if I had a NuGet package mismatch within a solution, but this is the only project in the solution that uses Hangfire.

I've tried deleting the hangfire database, recreating it, rebooting server - nothing helps.

I can't find anything on Google about this specific error either. What am I missing?

In a non Core site something would be added to the Web.Config to fix this - how is this done in .net Core? Where is the reference to the older version of the package coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Binding redirects can be added to an asp.net core application by putting an app.config file in the root directory and adding your redirects there.

Refer this link for more details:

http://blog.rytmis.net/2016/03/29/asp-net-core-and-assembly-binding-redirects/

Hope this helps